# issue with before/after function if I click on button too quickly

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I want to create an infine effect like carrousel on a gallery. 
I'm already using a plugin + a lot of jquery so I try to avoid using a carrousel plugin and do it myself.

I detected the first image position and add a piece of code to insert the last image in front of the first one if people click on previous to have an infinite effect.

```
$('#fp_prev_thumb').click(function(){
    //position of the first thumb
    var offset2 = $('.firstThumb').offset();
    var pos_first = offset2.left;
    if(pos_first >= -1){    
        $('ul.container li:first').before($('ul.container li:last'));
    }
});
```

It is working fine as long as a click slowly. But as soon as I click fast it seems to get lost, don't have time to load the image or something.

Do I need to add something or there is a better method to achieve the effect I want?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

unbind the click handler .unbind() as long your animation is running or your image is loading. rebind it .bind() after that.

Comment: I've used .stop() at the end, and it works. I will try to use bind() and unbind() in the future. Really need to get better at jQuery.